# Adding buttons to Firebase Push notifications (APNs)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

[Here is a picture of the notification that comes in Google Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZjis.jpg)

I want to set up the below buttons like this, if the user wants to turn it off or keep it,How can I add these buttons,is it coming as default? I integrated the APNs but my notifications seems not having these two buttons.Where can I add those?

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and send response from your server in clickaction key.

```
func setActionCategories() {

    let leaveOnAction = UNNotificationAction(
        identifier: "leaveon.action",
        title: "Leave On",
        options: [.foreground])

    let leaveonCategory = UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: "leaveon.category",
        actions: [leaveOnAction],
        intentIdentifiers: [],
        options: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(
            [leaveonCategory])

}
```

Server side:

```
{
    "to": "Your FCM ID",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Hello World",
        "title": "This is test message.",
        "click_action":"leaveon.category"
    }
}
```

Comment: "notification": {
        "body": "Hello World",
        "title": "This is test message.",
        "click_action":"leaveon.category"
    }
I tried adding this but then the notifications won't sending.Is there any possible reason? @Anish